# Android 11 intent share pdf unsupported attachment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-11

I want to intent to share pdf files to another app telegram, skype but when It's not working with Android 11 but for other version working fine. It shows a message Unsupported attachment. Below is picture that show message error

[image]

Below is coding Intent Share Pdf file

```
val builder = StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build())
    builder.detectFileUriExposure()

    val file = File(path)
    if (file.exists()) {
        val extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString())
        val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context, context.applicationContext.packageName.toString() + ".provider",
            file
        )
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType)
        intent.type = "application/pdf"
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file))
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
```

In Manifest declared

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>
```

Comment: First check if you are able to open that PDF file in other apps and then debug your code to store PDF file into your storage. I think there may be some issues when you store your file into storage.

Comment: Also refer official document once again for App data and files storing and sharing.

Comment: I can preview files but when share to social error

Comment: It's not working only Android 11.

Comment: Why this strict mode? Remove. `if (file.exists())` Change to `if (file.exists()&&file.canRead())`

Comment: `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file))` You used a FIleProvider so we did not look further as what could go wrong if you use a FileProvider? But then... much later.. we see that you use also Uri.fromFile()! How could you? VERY WRONG!